# How can I capitalize each word delimited by some characters in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, capitalize

I'm currently working with Pyspark and I'm facing a seemingly simple problem.

I want to capitalize the first letter of each word, even if the words are separated by characters in the following list:

```
delimiter_list = [' ', '(', '+', '/', '-']
```

Actually, `initcap` works only for words delimited by blank types.

Is there an efficient solution?
Here are some input-output examples:

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| baden-baden | Baden-Baden |
| markranstadt/brandenburg-kirchmöser | Markranstadt/Brandenburg-Kirchmöser |
| ostrow mazowiecki/bialystok | Ostrow Mazowiecki/Bialystok |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the delimiter isn't the same, you can first add a common delimiter, say `#` after each character in your list `delimiter_list` using `regexp_replace`:

```sql
regexp_replace(words, '(\\s|\\(|\\+|-|\\/)(.)', '$1#$2')
```

Now, you can split by `#` and transform the resulting array by capitalizing each element using `transform` function. Finally, join the array elements to get the original string using `array_join` function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "words_capitalized",
    F.expr(r"""
        array_join(
            transform(
                split(regexp_replace(words, '(\\s|\\(|\\+|-|\\/)(.)', '$1#$2'), '#'),
                x -> initcap(x)
            ),
            ""
        )
    """)
)

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
#|words                              |words_capitalized                  |
#+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
#|baden-baden                        |Baden-Baden                        |
#|markranstadt/brandenburg-kirchmöser|Markranstadt/Brandenburg-Kirchmöser|
#|ostrow mazowiecki/bialystok        |Ostrow Mazowiecki/Bialystok        |
#+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a UDF might be needed. You might need to manually curate the regex pattern because of the need to escape certain special characters, such as `(` and `+`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import re

df.show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------------------+
|words                              |
+-----------------------------------+
|baden-baden                        |
|markranstadt/brandenburg-kirchmöser|
|ostrow mazowiecki/bialystok        |
+-----------------------------------+


words_udf = F.udf(
    lambda w: re.sub(r'(^| |\(|\+|-|/)([a-z])', lambda x: x.group(1) + x.group(2).upper(), w)
)

df.select(words_udf('words').alias('words')).show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------------------+
|words                              |
+-----------------------------------+
|Baden-Baden                        |
|Markranstadt/Brandenburg-Kirchmöser|
|Ostrow Mazowiecki/Bialystok        |
+-----------------------------------+
```